# Simple MCMC in Python

Tags: python

I want to implement a simple mcmc in python but since i am new in this language
i have some mistakes that i cannot finger out.Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
def target(x) : 
    if x < 0 :
        print(0)  
    else: 
        print(np.exp(-x))
    return
    
    
target(1)
target(-1)
x = np.repeat(0,1000)
x[0] = 3     
for(i in range(2,1000)
  current  = x[i-1]
  proposal = current + np.random.normal(0,1,1)
    A = target(proposal)/target(current) 
  if np.random.uniform(0,1,1) < A : 
    x[i] = proposal       
  else: 
    x[i] = current        
plt.plot(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following runs, mainly after removing stray parens and having your function return values

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def target(value):
    if value < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.exp(-value)

x = np.repeat(0, 1000)
x[0] = 3
for i in range(2, 1000):
    current = x[i - 1]
    proposal = current + np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)
    A = target(proposal) / target(current)
    if np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1) < A:
        x[i] = proposal
    else:
        x[i] = current

plt.plot(x)
```

You may want to consider using an IDE like PyCharm, VS Code, or Atom to help identify mistakes in the future.